# Elixir quote/unquote

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to write a macro in elixir that creates a Phoenix router and a controller that has an action that should send message to the caller process (calling it from a test).

Here's a call to the macro:

```
start_server self(), "TestService", 8080, "/some_action", fn(conn, _) ->
  conn |> text("")
end
```

The problem is that the pid I'm passing from the test is not preserved when within the action. 
Line `#1` prints the correct pid and line `#2` prints the wrong pid. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something about `quote`/`unquote`, but I can't find what am I doing wrong?

Here's the macro definition:

```
defmacro start_server pid, name, port, path, handler do
  controller_name = String.to_atom("#{name}Controller")
  router_name = String.to_atom("#{name}Router")
  quote do
    IO.inspect(unquote(pid))                              # 1
    ctrl = defmodule unquote(controller_name) do
      use Phoenix.Controller

      def handle conn, msg do
        IO.inspect(unquote(pid))                          # 2
        send unquote(pid), {:request, unquote(path), unquote(name)}
        unquote(handler).(conn, msg)
      end
    end

    IO.inspect ctrl

    router = defmodule unquote(router_name) do
      use Phoenix.Router

      post unquote(path), unquote(controller_name), :handle
    end
    Application.put_env(:phoenix, unquote(router_name),
      port: unquote(port),
      debug_errors: true
    )
    IO.inspect router
    {:ok, pid} = unquote(router_name).start()
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrong pid?

Comment: Also, you can't serialize functions like that (you can't get an anonymous function and inject into a module, as a function is not a valid quoted expression). At first, it looks what you are trying to do won't work for different reasons but it is hard to suggest improvements because it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JoséValim I'm trying to run an http server and provide it's single controller action behaviour in each test.

Regarding quoting anonymous functions, here's what I get:

Comment: iex> quote do: fn (conn, _) -> conn |> text("") end


{:fn, [],
 [{:->, [],
   [[{:conn, [], Elixir}, {:_, [], Elixir}],
    {:|>, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
     [{:conn, [], Elixir}, {:text, [], [""]}]}]}]}

Comment: Sorry, but generating controller+router dynamically doesn't sound like a good solution to this problem. First, it will make your test suite expensive because compiling a bunch of modules, per test, will be expensive. Second, it won't be simple to understand, as macro code is complex. And finally, controllers are plugs, at least on master, which means you can test them directly: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/test/conn_helper.exs#L16-L18

Comment: Regarding the function, sorry, you are correct. you can unquote a quoted anonymous function. However, you can't unquote an anonymous function.